# Javascript given a number i want all possible combinations sum element array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, combinations

In javascript code i would all possible combinations of element that their sum give the number that i want:
example:

```
array = [2, 1, 2, 1]; 
number = 3; 
finalArray = [[2, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

or

```
array = [5, 5, 4, 4, 2] 
number = 10 
finalArray = [[5, 5], [4, 4, 2]]
```

This is my code but i had only first combination! I don't know why when i return recursive function, return also main function and it doesn't continue with another combination.
Can you help me, please? I follow this [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var numero = 3;
    var array = [2, 1, 2, 1];
    var tmpArray = [];
    var finalArray = [];

    $("#button").click(function() {
        combinationTableCard(array, numero, tmpArray);
        console.log(finalArray);
    })

    function combinationTableCard(cardArray, number, partialArray) {

            var n;
            var s = sumArray(partialArray);
            if (s == number) {
                finalArray.push(partialArray);
            }
            if (s >= number) {
                return;
            }
            for (i=0; i<cardArray.length; i++) {
                    n = cardArray[i];
                    var remaining = copyArray(cardArray, i+1, cardArray.length-1);

                    partialArray.push(n);
                    combinationTableCard(remaining, number, partialArray);
            }
        }

    function sumArray(v) {
            var total = 0;      
            if (v.length == 0) {
                return total;
            } else {
                for (i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
                    total += v[i];
                }
                return total;
            }
        }

        function copyArray(v, i, j) {
            var newV = new Array();
            var k = 0;
            for(i; i <= j; i++) {
                newV[k] = v[i];
                k++;
            }
            return newV;
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

In this function the problem is that you have not declared i as a local variable, so it is becoming global variable.function combinationTableCard and sumArray is using same variable i. Declare var i; and you will get the desired result.

Comment: OK i change it but now i obtain four array empty! I add partialArray.pop() after recursive call

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go. Still need to do some work on display**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

      <style>
      body {background-color:lightgray}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="container"></div>
      <button type="button" id="button">Click Me To Calculate combination!</button>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

        var target = 15;
        var array = [3,9,8,4,5,7,10];
        var tmpArray = [];
        var finalArray = [];

        $("#button").click(function() {
          sum_up_recursive(array, target, tmpArray);
          console.log(finalArray.toString());
          var finalText = '';
          finalArray.forEach(function(entry) {
            finalText = finalText + entry + '</br>';
          });
          $("#container").html(finalText);
        })

        function sum_up_recursive(numbers, number, partialArray) {

          var s=0;
          partialArray.forEach(function(entry) {
            s=s+entry;
          });
          if (s == target) {
            //finalArray.push(partialArray);
            var res = partialArray.join();  
            res=res.replace(/,/g , '+');
            res= res+"="+s;
             console.log(res);
             finalArray.push(partialArray);
            //$("#container").text(res);
          }
          if (s >= target) {
            return;
          }
          for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
            n = numbers[i];
            //var remaining = copyArray(cardArray, i+1, cardArray.length-1);
            var remaining = [];
            var remaining = numbers.slice(i+1);
            var partical_arr = partialArray.slice();       
            partical_arr.push(n);
            sum_up_recursive(remaining, target, partical_arr);
          }
        }

      });

      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```